# Testing Play Modules

Tags: module, selenium, automated-tests, playframework

Is there a standard way to set up Selenium tests for a Play module, as opposed to an application?  I can't find any info on how to do it.  It seems like it would need an application to run in, but when I set one up under `test/` its not happy.  When the app's controllers are in the `controller` package it says they should be in `testapp.app.controllers`.  When I change them to `testapp.app.controllers` it says they should be in `controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

having the folder structure in the question would help :).

Please check you are doing the following:

- Creating an application (*play new TestApp*)
- Verify it works (*play run TestApp*)
- Add a module to the application
- Add test controllers (and other classes/files) under **test/** folder in the module. NOTE: only test files go there
- Run the **main** application in test mode (*play test TestApp*)
- Go to http://localhost:9000/@tests to see the test interface

I just noticed your comment when you mention *play run testapp*. I think that's your error, you should run *play test testapp*  instead.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you make folder with a play-app just-tests. There you make an app which refers to your module and run the tests in it.